# Is it possible to commit two related tables in a SQLAlchemy transaction?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using the higher-level SQLAlchemy ORM via Flask-SQLAlchemy. I'd like to be able to create a number of tables and then commit them in a single transaction. However, one table relates to all the other tables and I'm unsure how to proliferate its ID before it actually exists. (Note that its primary key is an auto-incrementing value that doesn't exist until we actually execute the SQL.)

For example, say we have `TableA` and `TableB`. `TableB` has a column called `table_a_id`. The `TableA` ID is managed by the database; it auto-increments and doesn't exist until we create a row of `TableA`.

I'd like to be able to create `TableA` and `TableB` at the same time and if anything goes wrong rollback the transaction.

In a perfect world where magic is possible, my code would look something like:

```
try:
    a = TableA()
    b = TableB(table_a_id=a.id)  # a.id is None, since nothing has happened yet.
    db.session.commit()
except Exception:
    db.session.rollback()
```

Is it possible, maybe via a sub transaction, to fill in the value of `a.id` in the transaction?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `session.flush()` after creating your `a` object, that issues all pending SQL in the current transaction and *will* fill in auto-generated IDs. Later you can `commit()` or `rollback()` as needed.

Answer (score -1):

I have two table one is UnserInfo another one is clientInfo. In this case userInfoId is forign key in the clientInfo table. So first i save userInfo then save the clientInfo with the userInfo id

Here I user flask, marshmallow, flask-marshmallow, marshmallow-sqlalchemy, SQLAlchemy, flask-sqlalchemy.

I did in my project just like this

```
try:

    userInfo = UserInfo(
       userId=dataUserInfo['mobile'],
       password=dataUserInfo['password'],
       userTypeName='client')

    db.session.add(userInfo)     
    db.session.commit() # save userInfo in database
    dbUserInfoResult = userInfoDto.dump(userInfo).data # get userInfo id from database
    print('dbUserInfoResult.data.id: ', dbUserInfoResult['id'])

    clientInfo = ClientInfo(name=dataClintInfo['name'],
                      mobileCountryCode=dataClintInfo['mobileCountryCode'],
                      mobile=dataClintInfo['mobile'],
                      email=dataClintInfo['email'] if 'email' in dataClintInfo else None,
                      userInfoId=dbUserInfoResult['id'])

    db.session.add(clientInfo)
    db.session.commit()
except Exception:
    db.session.rollback()
```

Comment: That is not a good option for a transaction. In a transaction if your program aborts for some reason in mid-session, any uncommitted changes within are lost.

In your solution, if there will be a server crash there is a possibility that only the first commit will take place.